# Download image from SVG with Jersey

Tags: java, svg, highcharts, jersey

I have some SVG string from highcharts and I want to download it as an image (PNG).
The conversion is done using PNGTranscoder (Batik)

```
@POST
public Response getChartImage() throws Exception{

    String svg = "<svg xmlns:xlink..."; // can be ignored
    svg = svgDocumentConvertAndRevert(svg); // can be ignored

    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new StringReader(svg));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(baos);

    PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
    transcoder.transcode(input, output);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 500, 1);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();

    return Response.ok(imageData).build();

}
```

but what I'm getting is a bunch of text, something like

```
�PNG  IHDR�@��E� cHRMz&��...
```

Tried with `@Produces("image/*")` but didn't work...

Can I not save it as an image (real file) and allow user to download it? Trying to avoid unnecessary effort..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working, just that I was using Chrome's extension POSTman.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct mime type for the response something like

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
```

where response is a ServletResponse object.